# Хранение одного экземпляра класса в нескольких массивах

Tags: c++, ооп, классы

У меня имеется класс "рассказ", который нужно хранить в различных сборниках. Суть в том, что я использую указатели, т.е.

```
class Story
{
...
}

class Compilation
{
...
vector<Story*> stories;
...
}
```

Необходимо изменять информацию о рассказах. Здесь всё ясно, поскольку мы храним указатели, то всё будет меняться параллельно. Удаление из конкретного сборника тоже ясно. Но если окажется, что этот сборник - последний, где хранится наш рассказ, то как произвести удаление без утечки памяти? Если же мы хотим удалить рассказ навсегда, то как его удалить из всех сборников сразу?

Хранить сборники внутри рассказа тоже не вариант, так как необходимо устраивать поиск по сборникам, количеству рассказов в них и т.д.

Comment: Как вариант, использовать счётчик ссылок на объект. Когда рассказ добавляется в сборник или удаляется, он увеличивается или уменьшается на 1.Когда он равен 0 (сборник был последний), рассказ можно удалять. К слову, так работает технология COM в Windows.

Comment: @Streletz а при удалении из всех сборников делать полный перебор?

Comment: С какой целью???

Comment: @Streletz ну например нам надо удалить рассказ раз и навсегда отовсюду

Comment: Используйте `vector<shared_ptr<Story>> stories`. (У неё внутре <s>неонка</s> счётчик ссылок.)

Comment: @VladD тогда при удалении тем же erase'ом это гарантирует отсутствие утечек или как?

Comment: @GFalls: Каждый живой `shared_ptr` увеличивает счётчик ссылок. Когда количество ссылок станет равным нулю, вызовется `delete`.

Comment: @VladD и это работает на автомате?

Comment: @GFalls: А то! Написал маленький пример.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Вам нужно пользоваться `shared_ptr` вместо сырого указателя. При этом ваш объект будет удалён только когда последний указатель на него умрёт.

[Вот небольшой пример работы с ним](http://ideone.com/xaZBHa):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

class Story
{
    int n;
public:
    Story(int n): n(n) { cout << "story #" << n << " created" << endl; }
    ~Story() { cout << "story #" << n << " destroyed" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Story>> list1, list2;

    cout << "creating #1 and adding to first list" << endl;
    list1.emplace_back(make_shared<Story>(1));
    cout << "copying #1 to second list" << endl;
    list2.push_back(list1[0]);
    cout << "creating #2" << endl;
    auto story2 = make_shared<Story>(2);
    cout << "adding #2 to the second list" << endl;
    list2.push_back(story2);
    cout << "removing first ptr to story #2" << endl;
    story2 = nullptr;
    cout << "removing second ptr to story #2, now it will be destroyed" << endl;
    list2.resize(1);
    cout << "clearing first list" << endl;
    list1.clear();
    cout << "clearing second list, now story #1 will be destroyed" << endl;
    list2.clear();
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

Вывод:

> creating #1 and adding to first list
>   story #1 created
>   copying #1 to second list
>   creating #2
>   story #2 created
>   adding #2 to the second list
>   removing first ptr to story #2
>   removing second ptr to story #2, now it will be destroyed
>   story #2 destroyed
>   clearing first list
>   clearing second list, now story #1 will be destroyed
>   story #1 destroyed
>   done

---

Как правильно подсказывает @ixSci в комментариях, вы таки можете удалить элемент полностью во всех списках, если примете немного другой дизайн. Поделим списки на *владеющие* своими элементами (эти списки будут содержать `shared_ptr`), и *невладеющие* (эти списки будут содержать `weak_ptr`, невладеющий указатель). Тогда когда все сильные ссылки (`shared_ptr`) на объект умрут, слабые (`weak_ptr`) тоже станут недействительны.

Этот оформляется [так](http://ideone.com/WPVuhB):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class Story
{
    int n;
public:
    Story(int n): n(n) { cout << "story #" << n << " created" << endl; }
    ~Story() { cout << "story #" << n << " destroyed" << endl; }
    void print() { cout << "story #" << n << " reporting" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Story>> main_list;
    vector<weak_ptr<Story>> aux_list;

    cout << "creating and adding to owning list" << endl;
    main_list.emplace_back(make_shared<Story>(1));
    main_list.emplace_back(make_shared<Story>(2));
    cout << "copying to non-owning list" << endl;
    aux_list.push_back(main_list[0]);
    aux_list.push_back(main_list[1]);
    cout << "removing #2" << endl;
    main_list.resize(1);
    for (auto& weakptr : aux_list)
    {
        if (auto strongptr = weakptr.lock())
            strongptr->print();
        else
            cout << "(deleted entry)" << endl;
    }
    cout << "cleaning non-owning list" << endl;
    aux_list.erase(
        remove_if(begin(aux_list), end(aux_list), [](auto wp) { return wp.expired(); }),
        end(aux_list));
    for (auto& weakptr : aux_list)
    {
        if (auto strongptr = weakptr.lock())
            strongptr->print();
        else
            cout << "(cannot happen)" << endl;
    }
    cout << "done" << endl;
}
```

Вывод:

> creating and adding to owning list
>   story #1 created
>   story #2 created
>   copying to non-owning list
>   removing #2
>   story #2 destroyed
>   story #1 reporting
>   (deleted entry)
>   cleaning non-owning list
>   story #1 reporting
>   done
>   story #1 destroyed

Comment: Один вопрос, а если я захочу удалить конкретный рассказ отовсюду сразу?

Comment: @GFalls: Поскольку каждый `shared_ptr` вносит «вклад» в жизнь объекта, вы должны будете уничтожить (удалить из массива, обнулить, что угодно) все `shared_ptr`'ы на него. Сейчас добавлю в пример.

Comment: @GFalls: Добавил.

Comment: Вопрос в другом был. Пусть list1 и list 2 содержит story1 и story2 и еще есть list3 со story2 и list4 со story1. Я могу сразу отовсюду удалить story2, или же придется это делать перебором?

Comment: @GFalls: Вам придётся искать значение по спискам и удалять. Как-то так: http://ideone.com/8qgZ3e. Заметьте, что с сырым указателем вы точно так же не можете просто удалить объект, пока на него есть ссылки в векторах (очевидно, почему?)

Comment: да, спасибо, понял

Comment: Можно везде хранить weaked_ptr, а shared хранить только в одном месте, тогда, если удалить shared, то все ссылки поломаются. Просто нужно проверять жив ли ещё weaked при использовании. Это избавит от прочесывания всех массивов.

Comment: @ixSci: Хм, тоже хороший вариант. Напишите альтернативный ответ с кодом?

Comment: Зачем? У Вас замечательный ответ, если его дополните, он станет ещё лучше :)

Comment: @GFalls: Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 3):

Используйте интеллектуальный указатель `shared_ptr<Story>` - это именно то, что вам нужно.